# Assigning numpy array based on condition

Tags: python, numpy

What is a better way to write this numpy python code?

```
age[age < 20.0] = 0.0
age[age > 0.0] = 1.0
mature = age
```

Here, mature contains 1.0 for all values of age > 20.0, else 0.0

Comment: do you want to change `age`?

Comment: i do not care if it changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mature = age = (age > 20.0).astype(float)
```

`age > 20.0` is a boolean array. The `astype(float)` converts the array to float dtype, which changes True to 1.0 and False to 0.0.
Note that this also converts NaNs to 0.

---

To preserve NaNs, like your original code, you could use `np.clip`:

```
mature = age = np.clip(age-20, 0, 1)
```

---

For example,

```
In [90]: age = np.array([np.nan, 30, 20, 10])

In [91]: (age > 20.0).astype(float)
Out[91]: array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.])

In [92]: np.clip(age-20, 0, 1)
Out[92]: array([ nan,   1.,   0.,   0.])
```